# Change output filename prefix for DataFrame.write()

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, mapreduce

Output files generated via the Spark SQL DataFrame.write() method begin with the "part" basename prefix. e.g.

```
DataFrame sample_07 = hiveContext.table("sample_07");
sample_07.write().parquet("sample_07_parquet");
```

Results in:

```
hdfs dfs -ls sample_07_parquet/                                                                                                                                                             
Found 4 items
-rw-r--r--   1 rob rob          0 2016-03-19 16:40 sample_07_parquet/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 rob rob        491 2016-03-19 16:40 sample_07_parquet/_common_metadata
-rw-r--r--   1 rob rob       1025 2016-03-19 16:40 sample_07_parquet/_metadata
-rw-r--r--   1 rob rob      17194 2016-03-19 16:40 sample_07_parquet/part-r-00000-cefb2ac6-9f44-4ce4-93d9-8e7de3f2cb92.gz.parquet
```

I would like to change the output filename prefix used when creating a file using Spark SQL DataFrame.write(). I tried setting the "mapreduce.output.basename" property on the hadoop configuration for the Spark context. e.g.

```
public class MyJavaSparkSQL {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyJavaSparkSQL");
    JavaSparkContext ctx = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);
    ctx.hadoopConfiguration().set("mapreduce.output.basename", "myprefix");
    HiveContext hiveContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(ctx.sc());
    DataFrame sample_07 = hiveContext.table("sample_07");
    sample_07.write().parquet("sample_07_parquet");
    ctx.stop();
  }
```

That did not change the output filename prefix for the generated files.

Is there a way to override the output filename prefix when using the DataFrame.write() method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot change the "part" prefix while using any of the standard output formats (like Parquet). See this snippet from ParquetRelation [source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetRelation.scala#L386):

```
private val recordWriter: RecordWriter[Void, InternalRow] = {
  val outputFormat = {
    new ParquetOutputFormat[InternalRow]() {
      // ...
      override def getDefaultWorkFile(context: TaskAttemptContext, extension: String): Path = {
        // ..
        //  prefix is hard-coded here:
        new Path(path, f"part-r-$split%05d-$uniqueWriteJobId$bucketString$extension")
    }
  }
}
```

If you really must control the part file names, you'll probably have to implement a custom FileOutputFormat and use one of Spark's save methods that accept a FileOutputFormat class (e.g. [saveAsHadoopFile](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/JavaPairRDD.html#saveAsHadoopFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class))).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the output folder have only one `csv` file in it, we can rename this grammatically (or dynamically) using the below code. In the below code (last line), get all files from the output directory with `csv` type and rename that to a desired file name.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
val outputfolder_Path = "s3://<s3_AccessKey>:<s3_Securitykey>@<external_bucket>/<path>"     
val fs = FileSystem.get(new java.net.URI(outputfolder_Path), new Configuration())   
fs.globStatus(new Path(outputfolder_Path + "/*.*")).filter(_.getPath.toString.split("/").last.split("\\.").last == "csv").foreach{l=>{ fs.rename(new Path(l.getPath.toString), new Path(outputfolder_Path + "/DesiredFilename.csv")) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Agree with @Tzach Zohar..

---

After saving your dataframe in to HDFS or S3 you can rename using below...

The below scala example is ready to eat :-) means you can directly use in your code or util
After writing in to HDFS or S3 you can rename files using the below def..

#***Brief*** :

*1) get all the files under a folder using globstatus.

2) loop through and rename the file with prefix or suffix what ever is your case.

Note : Apache Commons are already available in hadoop clusters so no need for any further dependencies.*

```
/**
   * prefixHdfsFiles
   * @param outputfolder_Path
   * @param prefix
   */
  def prefixHdfsFiles(outputfolder_Path: String, prefix: String) = {
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{_}
    import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
    import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils._
    import java.io.File
    import java.net.URI

    val fs = FileSystem.get(new URI(outputfolder_Path), new Configuration())
    fs.globStatus(
      new Path(outputfolder_Path + "/*.*")).foreach { l: FileStatus => {
      val newhdfsfileName = new Path(getFullPathNoEndSeparator(l.getPath.toString) + File.separatorChar + prefix + getName(l.getPath.toString))
     // fs.rename(new Path(l.getPath.toString),newhdfsfileName )
      val change = s"""
        |original ${ new Path(l.getPath.toString) } --> new $newhdfsfileName
        |""".stripMargin
      println( change)
    }
    }
  }
```

Caller would be for example :

```
val outputfolder_Path = "/a/b/c/d/e/f/"
    prefixHdfsFiles(outputfolder_Path, "myprefix_")
```