# Access unique key (writeJobUUID) in parquet filename when saving PySpark DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet

I'm looking for a way to access the unique part(s) of the parquet filename when saving a Spark DataFrame as Parquet with PySpark.

Just read in [Change output filename prefix for DataFrame.write()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107581/change-output-filename-prefix-for-dataframe-write) that changing the output filename prefix for DataFrame.write() is not possible, though I like to know if there is a way to access the values used in RecordWriter to build up the filename.

I had a look at the [a source code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/datasources/parquet/ParquetRelation.scala#L491-L515), and saw that it's configuration.get("spark.sql.sources.writeJobUUID"), does this property gets initialized earlier, and is it also accessible through PySpark?

I'd like to use it for logging purposes, to match a specific Spark job to the parquet files written (so I can e.g. remove all output by a specific job in different output partitions).

Comment: You're probably better off adding some kind of JobID to your _data_, and _partitioning_ by that column - that way each job would create its own partitions which you can later read / write / delete at will, without having to dig into Parquet internals.

Comment: Thanks Tzach, that is indeed not a bad idea though we are already using a lot of partitioning and were keen on exploring this option. I guess it's not that straight-forward then..