# Spark save partitions with custom filename and gzip

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I would like to save my generated RDD partitions using a custom filename, like: `chunk0.gz`, `chunk1.gz`, etc. Hence, I want them to be gzipped as well.

Using `saveAsTextFile` would result in a directory being created, with standard filenames `part-00000.gz`, etc.

```
fqPart.saveAsTextFile(outputFolder, classOf[GzipCodec])
```

How do I specify my own filenames? Would I have to iterate through the RDD partitions manually and write to the file, and then compress the resulting file as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/36108367/5344058: although that question refers to saving Dataframes (and not RDDs), the same answer holds.