# partition the csv file on the basis of date and dump the partition into parquet

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I am very much new to scala and I have a csv file :

```
MSH     ModZId  ModProd     Date
1140000 zzz      abc    2/19/2018
1140000 zzz      xyz    2/19/2018
651     zzz      def    2/19/2018
651     zzz      ghi    2/19/2018
1140000 zzz      klm    2/19/2018
860000  zzz      mno    2/26/2018
860000  zzz      pqr    2/26/2018
122     zzz      stu    2/26/2018
122     zzz      wxy    2/26/2018
860000  zzz      ijk    2/26/2018
```

I need to partition the csv file on the basis of date and convert the partition on to the parquet like below:

Parquet Output 1:

```
MSH     ModZId  ModProd  Date
1140000 zzz     abc     2/19/2018
1140000 zzz     xyz     2/19/2018
651     zzz     def     2/19/2018
651     zzz     ghi     2/19/2018
1140000 zzz     klm     2/19/2018
```

Parquet Output 2 :

```
MSH     ModZId  ModProd  Date
860000  zzz     mno     2/26/2018
860000  zzz     pqr     2/26/2018
122     zzz     stu     2/26/2018
122     zzz     wxy     2/26/2018
860000  zzz     ijk     2/26/2018
```

Can anyone please help me .I am very much new and do not know how can i partition the csv file in scala on the basis of date

Answer (score 0):

If you already read the `csv` file and get the data as above, then you can use `partitionBy` while writing as `parquet` as below

```
df.write.partitionBy("Date").parquet("outputpath")
```

This creates a folder equal to the number of partition on Date.

Comment: not really,it is giving me date_2/19/2018 and i need only 2/19/2018 folder

Comment: Well for that you can write a separate script to change the name the spark jobs finished.

Comment: Take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36107581/change-output-filename-prefix-for-dataframe-write/36108367#36108367

Comment: i am not able to find any simple method to rename the file from date_2/19/2018 to 2/19/2018.Please suggest me

Comment: yes,shankar ,i was thinking the same to rename the folder .But ,i am struggling to rename all the folder .Not able to list all the folders  and then rename to required name

Comment: Can you please help me if you have anything to list all the directory and then rename it

Comment: no ,ext4 is the storage ,so i have folder with name Date_20190101,Date_20190201,Date_20190301.Can i rename them directly  to 20190101,20190201,20190301

Comment: Here is simple way in scala, change it as you want `    val outputDir = new File("output folder ")

    outputDir.listFiles().filter(file =>
      file.isDirectory && file.getName.startsWith("Date_")
    ).foreach(file => {
      val newfileName = file.getName.replace("Date_", "")
      file.renameTo(new File(outputDir, newfileName))
    })`

Comment: yes,trying this in my machine and can you please help me in one more thing that i have list of dates 20190101,20190201 and i need to delete the folder if exists with the same name .For e.g. location of folder is /usr/local/20190101 and list is containing element 20190101 then i need to delete the folder